# How to manualy register org.bluez service in d-bus?

Tags: bluetooth, dbus, bluez

I'm trying to turn raspberry pi into wireless media center which is controlled by mobile devices via bluetooth. Because i want to get advanced level in bluetooth application programming i use all d-bus methods of org.bluez service without the help of daemon bluetoothd. So i turn off bluetooth daemon.

```
update-rc.d bluetooth disable
```

After that d-bus tells there are no such service like org.bluez. For example i want to get information about bluetooth adapters:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.bluez / org.bluez.Manager.ListAdapters
```

and i get

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.bluez was not provided by any .service files
```

I can't understand how bluetoothd registers in d-bus. I know ([according to d-bus manual](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/system-activation.txt)) that user has to create special .service file but what bluetooth executable should be used in this file?

Comment: bluetoothd provides the org.bluez service. If you disable it then you can't use that service. You would need to implement the entire service yourself. I would not recommend that. I think what you want to do is to act as a client that interacts with that the service. bluetoothd will then handle all the low level bluetooth details. And you can concentrate on the higher level BT behaviours that you want your device to implement.

Comment: @Alan Au, thanks for the comment. All low level bluetooth details can be done through d-bus interface. bluetoothd turns up bluetooth device, creates an agent (interface for security problems and pairing with external devices) etc. I want to do this manually. I can create another bluetooth agent but i don't know how it will interract with bluetoothd.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. bluetoothd is the service provider for all the bluez dbus APIs. If you disable it then you can't use any of those. So I don't know what you mean by "all low level bluetoth details can be done through dbus interface". Of course you can create another agent. And you don't disable bluetoothd to do that. The bluez dbus APIs have been designed exactly for that. You do that via the [Agent dbus api](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/agent-api.txt).